# IJ000305: Connection error occured: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener

Tags: java, connection-pooling, wildfly-8, oracle12c

We are using Wildfly8.2 server. The DB connection pool managed by Wildfly server is not able to reconnect (or to regenerate a valid/managed connection pool) after the connections are invalidated by the database server. 
Please see the below error:

```
2016-05-03 11:35:43,662 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener] (NRG) IJ000305: Connection error occured: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@231fd521[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@7ea688d0 connection handles=1 lastUse=1462286812044 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@794f665c mcp=SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool@43e70a99[pool=DSNAME] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@7482a7a7[connectionListener=231fd521 connectionManager=3d2232ff warned=false currentXid=null productName=Oracle productVersion=Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options jndiName=java:jboss/DSNAME] txSync=null]: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapterInternalException: Unexpected error<br>
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.broadcastConnectionError(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:644)<br>
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.connectionError(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:610)<br>
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkException(WrappedConnection.java:1640)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.checkException(WrappedStatement.java:1267)<br>
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:467)
    at com.abc.app.beans.ReconcileInfo.getNextMessage(ReconcileInfo.java:412) [classes:]
    at com.abc.app.beans.GroupInfo.sendMessage(GroupInfo.java:819) [classes:]<br>
    at com.abc.app.app.GroupSendThread.send(GroupSendThread.java:112) <br>[classes:]
    at com.ctsu.rdts.app.GroupSendThread.run(GroupSendThread.java:66) [classes:]
Caused by: java.lang.ThreadDeath<br>
    at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:850) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at com.abc.app.app.HttpDequeue.stopThread(HttpDequeue.java:876) [classes:]
    at com.abc.app.app.HttpDequeue.clearLocks(HttpDequeue.java:397) [classes:]
    at com.abc.app.app.HttpDequeue.run(HttpDequeue.java:383) [classes:]
```

Comment: Was it working earlier? Is it the first time you are trying to connect to Oracle 12c? Also, can you share parts of your connect string?

Comment: We have been connecting to 12c with other applications which uses Spring & Hibernate but the current application is built on servlets and jsps also we are using thread. Would that be a problem? This is the connection URL which we are using <br />
<connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@host_name:port:db_name</connection-url>

Comment: Well one important difference wrt 12c is we need to use [service name](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3513362?tstart=0) instead of `db_name`.

Comment: @learningloop I tried changing to service name as suggested but it throw me the below error    <BR/>
Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Comment: The error suggests the connection url used is of incorrect type, it should be in the following format `jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@//hostname:portnumber/servicename` if that didn't work you can try the following: `jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=service_name)))`

Comment: @learningloop I do not have any problem connecting with database. Seems I have a problem with multi threads running in my application. If you see the stacktrace which I have in the question there is a line "Caused by: java.lang.ThreadDeath" Can you suggest anything on this?

Comment: @Usha, did you manage to solve it? I seem to have the same kind of issue.

Comment: @SimonCedergrenMalmqvist, I am still stuck with this issue. But I have found the root cause for this issue. Root cause : We are trying to stop the Thread by using interrupt() method whereas it doesn't kill the Thread. In my case there are thousands of Threads running since we use interrupt method the connection object gets locked.